# Add exception to Firewall script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

So im not going to take credit for this script, but i need a little help with this.
I'm new to PS, so please excuse the stupid questions.

I need to add exceptions to this script such as the "192.168." / "10.0." range.

I know it would be something like:
 IF remoteaddress = "blah" then skip.

But i have no idea how to format it for powershell.

If someone could show me or point me in the right direction?

```
#Checks for IP addresses that used incorrect password more than 10 times
#within 24 hours and blocks them using a firewall rule 'BlockAttackers'

#Check only last 24 hours
$DT = [DateTime]::Now.AddHours(-24)

#Select Ip addresses that has audit failure
$l = Get-EventLog -LogName 'Security' -InstanceId 4625 -After $DT | Select-Object @{n='IpAddress';e={$_.ReplacementStrings[-2]} }

#Get ip adresses, that have more than 10 wrong logins
$g = $l | group-object -property IpAddress | where {$_.Count -gt 10} | Select -property Name

#Get firewall object
$fw = New-Object -ComObject hnetcfg.fwpolicy2

#Get firewall rule named 'BlockAttackers'
$ar = $fw.rules | where {$_.name -eq 'BlockAttackers'}

#Split the existing IPs into an array so we can search it for existing IPs
$arRemote = $ar.RemoteAddresses -split(',')

#Only collect IPs that aren't already in the firewall rule
$w = $g | where {$_.Name.Length -gt 1 -and !($arRemote -contains $_.Name + '/255.255.255.255') }

#Add the new IPs to firewall rule
$w| %{
  if ($ar.RemoteAddresses -eq '*') {
    $ar.remoteaddresses = $_.Name
  }else{
    $ar.remoteaddresses += ',' + $_.Name
  }
}

#Write to logfile
if ($w.length -gt 1) {
  $w| %{(Get-Date).ToString() + ' ' + $_.Name >> '.\blocked.txt'}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a white list of IPs that you never want to block.

Then it's a case failing out of your loop if you encounter a whitelisted IP.

```
$whitelist = @("10.0.0.1", "192.168.1.1")
..
if ($IP -match $whitelist)  { 
    #do nothing, debug here 
} else { 
    #block things 
}
```

This may be a bit tricky for you at your level of powershell experience, but take a look at [wail2ban](https://github.com/glasnt/wail2ban), a powershell script I've created as a solution to this exact problem.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I would love to use wail2ban, but the restrictions of GFIMAX, won't allow me to deploy it on a mass scale. (50+ servers), hence why we are just looking to do a very basic script. like the one posted. because we know what IP's are going to access what server its just the constant annoyance of coming in, in the morning and seeing 5000 attempts on one server.

Comment: I'm unsure what GFIMAX limits you to, but I created wail2ban for a fleet of similar scale. Originally it just checked every X minutes if there were too many events as per parameters, but I changed it to listen for new log events, for simplicity. Ideally it could be a service, but that wasn't something I had time to do. If you read though the README you should be able to at least see the logic in what it tries to do and then apply in your own script.